# Time series data axis, in R

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I have nearly a quarter of a million data rows like below.

it consists of readings at 15-minute intervals over 7 years.

[image]

```
Propertimeseries <- ts(Proper)
plot.ts(Propertimeseries)
```

The above code is what I used to get the graphs below.

[image]

I want to have basically the line plot that can be seen on the bottom section of the graph with reading value on the y axis and the date on one x-axis. with a secondary x-axis going from 00:15:00 to 00:00:00 for each day.

Any help would be more than appreciated!

Thank you

EDIT*
@dcruvolo
this is the output for dput()
`enter code here`[[image][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojIXO.png)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your question. Can you provide a sample of your dataset? You can do this using the `dput()`  function in base R. For more information, see [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: @dcruvolo Thank so much for your reply please find the output of (dput()) at the end of the question above

Comment: I will paste the output below

Comment: 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 9, 10, 9, 11, 11, 9, 10, 7, 11, 10, 
9, 10, 10, 9, 9, 10, 9, 9, 8, 10, 9, 10, 9, 9, 8, 9, 9, 7, 9, 
9, 6, 9, 9, 9, 7, 9, 10, 9, 9, 10, 10, 8, 11, 10, 10, 11, 11, 
12, 13, 16, 17, 15, 17, 15, 14, 17, 16, 15, 16, 15, 14, 16, 15, 
15, 15, 19, 17, 15, 15, 14, 14, 14, 13, 14, 14, 14, 13, 13, 14, 
12, 12, 14, 13, 11, 11, 12, 11, 11, 8, 11, 9, 11, 12, 10, 10, 
11, 10, 10, 11, 10, 9, 10, 10, 11, 9, 8, 10, 11), .Dim = c(263520L, 
3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Date", "Time", "Reading")), .Tsp = c(1, 
263520, 1), class = c("mts", "ts", "matrix"))